# Wordpress Replace words in already existed Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple words that i need to replace on posts that they are already added on the WordPress, but I don't want to change the full content, I need only the WordPress post output.

I have this code but is not working ... and I can't find how WordPress working about this ...

```
 function SC_Replace_Words_On_Posts() {
  $Replace_Words_Array                                                       = array(
   'aaa'                                                                      => 'aa',
  );
  
  if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
   $Post_ID = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
  } else {
   $Post_ID = false;
  }
  
  $Post_Content                                                              = get_post_field('post_content', $Post_ID);
     
  if($Post_Content != '' && is_array($Replace_Words_Array) && !empty($Replace_Words_Array)) {
   foreach($Replace_Words_Array as $Find_Word => $Replace_Word) {
    $Post_Content                                                              = SC_replaceWithCase($Find_Word, $Replace_Word, $Post_Content);
   }
  }
   
  return $post;

 }
 
 add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", "SC_Replace_Words_On_Posts");
```

Comment: You are adding filter which will trigger function call when post is saved, but you mentioned that post is already added - that may be a problem. 

So, I can see a few options here

1. change directly in the database if that's one time thing and you just need to run a replacement. You can run an update query and replace words only in the post content.
2. white a script which will loop through all posts in the database and re-save them with changes applied.

Comment: use filter... the_content

Comment: if you have access to DB then you can just find and replace in DB for wp_posts table. it will be easy for you but just take DB backup before do any action